# Boundless OpenGeo Explorer fails with Python errors

Tags: qgis, python, boundless-suite, geoserver-explorer

I am running this stack on a Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter.

- PostgreSQL 9.3.10
- PostGIS 2.2.0
- PGAdmin III 1.18.1
- Geoserver 2.7.3
- QGIS 2.12.0
- Boundless OpenGeo Explorer 0.6.2

Everything runs rather fine, except Creation of Geoserver Catalogs and publishing. Catalogs can't be created after the Default one, but the publishing works after a fashion, i e table names can't be changed for instance. The following two log excerpts show the Catalog error and the publishing error.

```
2015-11-12T20:27:28 1 Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "C:/Users/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\gui\gsexploreritems.py", line 231, in <lambda>  
 createCatalogAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.addGeoServerCatalog(explorer))  
 File "C:/Users/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\gui\gsexploreritems.py", line 235, in addGeoServerCatalog  
 dlg = DefineCatalogDialog(explorer)  
 File "C:/Users/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\gui\dialogs\catalogdialog.py", line 14, in __init__  
 self.initGui()  
 File "C:/Users/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\gui\dialogs\catalogdialog.py", line 92, in initGui  
 self.certWidget = QgsAuthConfigSelect( keypasssupported = False)  
 AttributeError: 'keypasssupported' is not a Qt property or a signal  

2015-11-12T20:28:36 1 Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "C:/Users/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\gui\qgsexploreritems.py", line 59, in <lambda>  
 publishProjectAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.publishProject(tree, explorer))  
 File "C:/Users/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins\opengeo\gui\qgsexploreritems.py", line 102, in publishProject  
 tree.findAllItems(catalog)[0].refreshContent(explorer)  
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'refreshContent'
```

Comment: Thanks Bernhard for the makeup on my post. That is how I wanted it to look.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you somehow solved it (QGIS 2.12.0)?